# Radio Group as Circular Page Indicator

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager, radio-group, viewpagerindicator

I am trying to use RadioGroup as a CircularPageIndicator. The problem is with the RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener. It seems to call it self when **onPageSelected** is called. However I want it to work vice versa i.e. when I select a radioButton it should change a view based on the location of the Array index being provided. However it seems as if onCheckedChange is never called when I change a check on the radio button and so onCheckedChange never triggers.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener, OnPageChangeListener {

    ViewPager mImagePager;
    ImagePagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;
    RadioGroup mPageIndicator;
    boolean swipeChange = false;


    int[] mRadioButtonIds = new int[] { R.id.radio0, R.id.radio1, R.id.radio2, R.id.radio3, R.id.radio4 };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        initComponents();
        mPageIndicator.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
        mImagePager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);
        mImagePager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);
    }

    /**
     * 
     */
    private void initComponents() {
        mPageIndicator  = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);
        mImagePager     = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.imgPager);
        mPagerAdapter   = new ImagePagerAdapter();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int pSelectedPagePosition) {
        swipeChange = true;
        mPageIndicator.check(mRadioButtonIds[pSelectedPagePosition]);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
        if (!swipeChange) {
            int itemPosition = Arrays.asList(mRadioButtonIds).indexOf(checkedId);
            mImagePager.setCurrentItem(itemPosition, true);
            swipeChange = false;
        }
    }

}
```

Note : I don't want to use any third party code/lib to create a custom Circular Page Indicator.

Can any one please point a mistake here. Is there a reason for the RadioGroup not to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to take a look at the documentation!

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/radiobutton.html